# Advanced typsetting multiline equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I want to typset a multiline equation which should be grouped by `\Theta`.
Using `multiline`, `flalign` nor `dmath` led to the desired output since the output could not be left aligned to a second indention level.

I did "trick" with an `\phantom{}` command, but I think there must be a better way to typeset the equation. Do you have any ideas?

Here is a minimum example which you also find on [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/9248465rdwrbcxrmwym).

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    U & = \frac{1}{a+b+c} \cdot \bigg(      \\
      & -\Theta_{x}  \cdot  \Big( a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i \Big) \\
      & + \Theta_{y} \cdot \Big(           a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i \\
      & \phantom{+ \Theta_{y} \cdot \Big(} +2 (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i) \\
      & \phantom{+ \Theta_{x} \cdot \Big(} -2 (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i) \\ 
      & + \Theta_{z} \cdot \Big(           a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i \\
      & \phantom{+ \Theta_{y} \cdot \Big(} +2 (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i) \\
      & \phantom{+ \Theta_{x} \cdot \Big(} -2 (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i)\Big) \bigg) \\      
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This example renders as:

[image: Multiline Equation]

Comment: The overleaf link shows that your example is just an example, not the actual text you want to set. If this were the real text you could make things easier on your reader by precomputing some common expressions - for example `ABCDE = a+b+c+d+e` . Maybe that strategy will work for you.

Answer (score 6):

Taking symmetries into account, you can do as follows, but the final setup of course depends on the real structure of your formulas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
U= \frac{1}{a+b+c} \Bigl(
    &-\Theta_{x} & ( a     &+ b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i ) \\
    &+\Theta_{y} & \bigl(a &+ b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i \\
    &            &         &+ 2(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i) \\
    &            &         &- 2(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i)\bigr) \\
    &+\Theta_{z} & \bigl(a &+ b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i \\
    &            &         &+ 2(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i) \\
    &            &         &- 2(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i)\bigr)\Bigr)
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution the most. It is yet simple to read in the code and aligns the equation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Using `aligned` inside of the `align*` environment:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
U={}& \frac{1}{a+b+c} \cdot \biggl(  \\
    &-\Theta_{x} \cdot \Bigl( a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i \Bigr) \\
    &+\Theta_{y} \cdot \begin{aligned}[t]\Bigl( &a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i \\
                          &+2 (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i) \\
                          &-2 (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i)\Bigr) \end{aligned} \\ 
    &+\Theta_{z} \cdot \begin{aligned}[t]\Bigl( &a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i \\
                          &+2 (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i) \\
                          &-2 (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i)\Bigr)\biggr) \end{aligned} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I also tried to "stack" an `align` environment, but didn't use `aligned`, so it didn't work... Since the plus and minus operators of the beginning of the second indention are not aligned, I like the result of @egreg solution more.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with a TABstack.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{mathtools,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\setstackgap{L}{23pt}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\TABbinary
\begin{document}
\[
\tabularCenterstack{rll}{
    U  & = \mathrlap{\frac{1}{a+b+c} \cdot \bigg(}&      \\
      & -\Theta_{x}&  \cdot  \Big( a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i \Big) \\
      & + \Theta_{y}& \cdot \Big(           a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i \\
      &  &+2 (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i) \\
      &  &-2 (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i) \\ 
      & + \Theta_{z}& \cdot \Big(           a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i \\
      &  &+2 (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i) \\
      &  &-2 (a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i)\Big) \bigg)     
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And by merely flipping the `U  &=` to `U  =&`, the theta terms get shifted rightward:

[image]